# How to correctly link a C++ library that has different behaviors depending on its compilation?

Tags: c++, linker, visibility

I have a library called `Print` and the function `println`, which mimics `printf`. If compiled with the directive `USE_DEBUG_PRINT`, `println` actually prints something. If compiled without this define, it prints nothing.

Then I want to use this library inside another library, let's call it `A`. `A` uses `Print` with this directive defined. Another library, 'B', uses 'Print' **without** this directive, so `println` has different behaviors for them.

However, when compiling into an application, depending on the link order, `B` will use `println` from `A`, or the opposite. This happens because the `println` symbol is defined for both of the libs, so the linker just picks the first.

How can I, instead, make `Print` "private" for these libs? I don't want anyone using `A` or `B` to have access to the `println` function regardless, so they can just be "merged" together, keeping `println` out of the `1.txt` files, being used only in their implementations.

I'm using Clang and CMake to generate both libs and the app. `Print` is an object library, while the other ones are static.

Comment: The joys of ODR violation.

Comment: Are you talking about static linking or dynamic linking?

Comment: are they static or shared libraries? If they're static there's nothing you can do other than giving the functions different names/namespaces

Comment: Also, in any case, if you managed to get a definition in each library, that seems to indicate that `println` is an inline function. In that case you can't even prevent it being already inlined at call sites. Even if it isn't inline you would need to make sure that it is defined in a separate translation unit without any link time optimization enabled or (for dynamic linking) that `-fsemantic-interposition` is enabled ((for now?) default on gcc, but not clang).

Comment: you can link whatever version of library you want, just use make/cmake/...... and pass that define through compilation parameters

Comment: "_Print is an object library,_": What do you mean with "object library"? More importantly: Is `println` an inline function and where/how is it defined? How do you manage to get the libraries to compile with different versions of the definition?

Comment: It sounds like you sort of have 2 libraries with identical API's and mostly identical functionality that you maintain a single code base for. I don't know if println() is used internally to the library. If not, you might try modifying the library and include printlnDebug() and printlnDoNothing(). Then you could provide 2 different .h file interfaces for clients. Those .h files would provide a trivial routing println() _in an anonymous namespace._ With more extensive mucking with the library, this might also be modified to handle the println() used internally case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by doing the following:

- Print is now an interface, containing just a header file.
- `println` is marked as `static`.

This way, it can be included in any `.cpp` file, and be compiled with the options it defined without affecting other compilations.